# How to rearrange characters in a string?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I have a string like this:

```
1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h
```

And I need to rearrange it as follow:

```
a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8
```

Do you understand what I mean? For each two characters, the numerical character swapping place with the following letter, i.e. from `1a` change it to `a1`

So my question is **how to rearrange the numerical characters and letters in the string**? My string always has the said pattern, i.e. one integer then followed by a letter then followed by a integer then followed by a letter and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with simple regex replacement.

```
Dim input As String = "1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(a, "(\d)(\w)", "$2$1")
Console.WriteLine(input & " --> " & output)
```

Output:

```
1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h --> a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8
```

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this should do what you want:

```
    Dim input As String
    input = "1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h"

    Dim tmp As Char()
    tmp = input.ToCharArray()

    For index = 0 To tmp.Length - 2 Step 2
        Dim a As Char
        a = tmp(index + 1)
        tmp(index + 1) = tmp(index)
        tmp(index) = a
    Next

    Dim output As String
    output = New String(tmp)
```